# Can I get my salt from a database and then check the password in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication, passwords

I've recently added a class which uses unique salts stored in the members table. This was my login script before I used salts:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT id, username FROM member WHERE username = ? AND pass = ?';

    $result = $this->DB->query($sql, array($username, $pass));
    foreach($result as $record) {
        $user = [
    "id" => $record['id'],
    "username" => $record['name']];
}

if (empty($user)) {
        // Display errors
    } else {
            // Login by sending the array of data to login function
        self::login($user);
    }
```

Now, I want to get the salts too. Is there any way I can do this without using more than 1 query? I can make it work by starting with a query to get the user pass and salt but is there a better way. It feels kind of like a hack or is it simply unavoidable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do (assuming the `pass` is created as `MD5($salt . $password)` and that you have column named `salt` inside your `member` table):

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, username FROM member WHERE username = ?
           AND pass = MD5(CONCAT(member.salt, ?))';
```

This way MySQL directly checks stored hash created after *[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)-ing* inserted password and salt.

Comment: So you are sending unhashed password over the network, well done.

Comment: @Santhos most php+mysql hosting I've encountered host both web hosting and database on the same or within one network...  If you cannot trust that environment don't have your application hosted there at first place. If you need to use "*external*" DB you always can use [SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your database does not provide a secure hash function for passwords, `MD5` and any other fast hash function should never be used for hashing passwords.

That's why you cannot check your password hash with a single query. Instead you can make a single query to your database, getting the password hash:

```
SELECT username, pass FROM member WHERE username = ?
```

Now you can check `pass` with php instead of doing it with SQL. This way you need only 1 query too, but can use a secure hash algorithm. The salt can be stored in the same `pass` field, together with the hash value.

It's recommended to use **BCrypt**. PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` ready, to simplify this task. There is a [compatibility pack](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) for PHP 5.3/5.4 available, downloadable at [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).